# What is this method name for comparing two financial time series by their difference (subtraction)?

Tags: time-series, terminology, paired-data, finance

I am trying to find a reference/name for what I am doing for explaining it in an academic work.

My scenario is that: I have financial time-series A and B. I want to answer if A outperforms B or vice-versa.

In this visual example, series `output_1` and `output_40` are very similar, but how to be more precise if 1 or 4 is better? Because the follow almost the same path, but they meet more or less at the same point in the end.

[image: series comparison]

What I am doing, intuitively:

By plotting `1` - `40`, I can see that (green series) is usually positive; thus, series `1` usually is doing better than series `40`. Had it been the opposite, I would say that series `40` would be outperforming series `1`.

I need a name/reference for that, but I am not even sure how to search for it.
I've tried things like:

- two  time series difference
- intuitive way to compare two time series by difference
- time series difference
- financial relative performance analysis
- compare financial time series subtract

Comment: Perhaps *cumulative return on a long-short portfolio* (long in 1, short in 40)?

Comment: I don't think it needs any fancy name. Calculating and plotting the difference.